# iCloud holiday calendar appeared in Calendar app

Tags: icloud, calendar, ical

I opened up Calendar this morning and a new calendar appeared under "Other"

The calendar is Mexican Holidays and it is a calendar subscription from iCloud. I didn't add it nor do I live in Mexico. I have seen this on a few Macs in our office all running 10.9.x

Calendars include Mexican Holidays, Canadian Holidays and Hong Kong Holidays.

Is anyone else seeing this behaviour?

Comment: sounds a bit like some one get access to your iCloud account or maybe yours and another account from someone else got some how linked to the same iCloud account. I think you should ask Apple if they can find out, if the second thing happend. - Also it could possibly be that (you said on multiple macs at office - they possibly have all a shared calendar) some at your office added those calendars to the shared one and not to his own - if you really think that it is a Bug of the Calendar App or of the iCloud then you should fill a Apple Bugreport

Answer (score 1):

Managed to confirm this with a few admins in NZ/Aus. The Show Holiday Calendar is on and for users in NZ there doesn't seem to be a NZ Holiday calendar so we are getting results such as Hong Kong, Canada and Mexico...

Users in Australia are seeing the correct Australia Holidays calendar.

However we aren't exactly sure what triggered the calendars to show in the first place...